# How to determine parameters that satisfy a given equation

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am working for a mathematical model in which I intend to fit the model itself to statistical data to determine the values that my parameters must have. I am dealing with equations of the sort:

"number=a+b+c", and I wish to find all the combinations of a, b c greater or equal to 0 that may satisfy this condition (I know that there should only be one).
I have thought of a brute force approach, but it would be unrealistic to solve this problem in that way.

There has to exist some sort of function to solve this. I have been reading on data annealing, but it doesnt do the trick, and normal data fitting doesn't really make sense, since i don't have "points" to which I must find an equation, but rather i just need to find those three parameters.

Comment: are you talking about simulated annealing? - Can you give a simplified version of your problem for us to get a sense what you want to optimize?

Comment: Without specifics, it's impossible to recommend anything. Your task, as given, could be interpreted as simple [System of linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) right now. Without any specifics, it's hard to recognize some mathematical structure to be exploited.